# how to extract text from an xml using groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I want to grab a text within an xml. Example below:

```
<parentxml>
  <xml1/>
  <xml2/>
  <xml3/>
  <xx:totalPrice xmlns:xx='test'>111</xx:totalPrice>
  <xml5/>
</parentxml>
```

How am I able to extract the text of total price '111'? Below is the code I am trying:

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText( response )
def ns = xml.'**'.find {it.name().contains('totalPrice')}
```

Comment: `ns.text()` - also your example XML is borked

Comment: i realise I need to do contains but when I try and use ns.text(), it is givng me an error and I believe it is a contains. Can I use a contains instead of ==?

Comment: I updated question so you can see what I'm trying

Comment: Never mind, I got it working

Comment: def ns = xml.'**'.find{it.name().toString().contains('totalPrice')}
log.info ns.text()